# Any information found for CVE-2022-22965 (Spring2Shell) for Oracle or SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Any information found for CVE-2022-22965 (Spring2Shell) for Oracle or SQL Server?   All quiet from their support organizations as of today.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2022/04/04/springshell-rce-vulnerability-guidance-for-protecting-against-and-detecting-cve-2022-22965/

Comment: The SQL Server engine doesn't use Java, at all.